# WooCommerce - Flat rate shipping based on X quantity steps?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

We need to run WooCommerce flat rate shipping rate based on every X items in the cart, for example:

- 1-5 Items: Delivery = £5
- 6-10 Items: Delivery = £10
- 11-15 Items: Delivery = £15
- *and so on…*

It's essentially £1 per item, but it's in brackets of £5, so 3 items would be £5, and 7 items would be £10, for example.

I'm hoping this is achievable with the out of the box shipping rates, or alternatively, I'd be relatively comfortable writing a theme function, if required - but the client has a limited budget on this.

I've tried looking for more reference on the available shortcodes that I can use in the advanced shipping options, but can't seem to find a way to achieve the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that, you need to use a hooked function in `woocommerce_package_rates` filter hook, targeting "Flat rate" shipping method.

In shipping settings for **flat rate** shipping method you will **set a cost of `5`**.

Each 5 items **step**, the shipping cost will be increased by 5: 
• From 1 to 5 Items: Delivery = **`5`** 
• From 6 to 10 Items: Delivery = **`10`** 
• From 11 to 15 Items: Delivery = **`15`** 
• *And so on…*

Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'different_rates_based_on_quantity_steps', 10, 2 );
function different_rates_based_on_quantity_steps( $rates, $package ){

    $items_count  = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); // Cart item count
    $items_change = 5; // number of items needed to increase the cost each time
    $rate_operand = ceil( $items_count / $items_change ); // Operand increase each 5 items here

    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        // Targetting "Flat rate"
        if( 'flat_rate' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $has_taxes = false;

            // Set the new cost
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $rate->cost * $rate_operand;

            // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $tax > 0 ){
                    // New tax calculated cost
                    $taxes[$key] = $tax * $rate_operand;
                    $has_taxes = true;
                }
            }
            // Set new taxes cost
            if( $has_taxes )
                $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

> **Refresh the shipping caches:** *(required)*
>
> 1. This code is already saved on your active theme's function.php file.
> 2. The cart is empty
> 3. In a shipping zone settings, disable / save any shipping method, then enable back / save.

Comment: Dude! You're a life saver! I owe you a beer! Anyhow, I need this tweaked. Instead doubling the shipping by the total of items in the cart. Can this be done by the number of items in a specific shipping class? In other words, Say I have 2 types of products with a shipping class each (Large and Small). Small is something that can be included in the large package or sold by itself. I don't need the shipping cost to double just cause I added more than 5 of those since they don't affect the size of the enitre package. Only the Large class affects the size after 5 of them.

Comment: How can change this `$items_count  = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()` to get the count of a shipping class alreaady established or slugged (large-shipping). Something like `$items_count  = WC()->cart->get_shipping_class('large-shipping')`, Which I obviously know it doesn't exist lol

Answer (score 1):

Still can't comment so I need to post this fix to the above awesome answer.

For the rate calc to work properly, the `return $rates;` line must be outside the cart loop.

The complete function should be:

```
$step_change = 5; // Steps for item
$item_count = 0;

// Checking in cart items
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){

// If we find the shipping class
if( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class() == $slug_class_shipping ){

$item_count += $cart_item['quantity']; // Cart item count
$rate_operand = ceil( $item_count / $step_change ); // Operand increase each # items here

foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
    // Targetting "Flat rate"
    if( 'flat_rate' === $rate->method_id ) {
        $has_taxes = false;

        // Set the new cost
        $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $rate->cost * $rate_operand;

        // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
        foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
            if( $tax > 0 ){
                // New tax calculated cost
                $taxes[$key] = $tax * $rate_operand;
                $has_taxes = true;
            }
        }
        // Set new taxes cost
        if( $has_taxes )
            $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
     }
   }    
 }
  return $rates;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a specific class you must check each item in the cart, and check with the slug of the class which items correspond, in this way:

First add the woocommerce_package_rates filter

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'different_rates_based_on_quantity_steps', 10, 2 );
```

Then insert the function

```
function different_rates_based_on_quantity_steps ( $rates, $package ){

$slug_class_shipping = 'books'; // Slug of the shipping class
$step_change = 5; // Steps for item
$item_count = 0;

// Checking in cart items
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){

// If we find the shipping class
if( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class() == $slug_class_shipping ){

$item_count += $cart_item['quantity']; // Cart item count
$rate_operand = ceil( $item_count / $step_change ); // Operand increase each # items here

foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
    // Targetting "Flat rate"
    if( 'flat_rate' === $rate->method_id ) {
        $has_taxes = false;

        // Set the new cost
        $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $rate->cost * $rate_operand;

        // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
        foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
            if( $tax > 0 ){
                // New tax calculated cost
                $taxes[$key] = $tax * $rate_operand;
                $has_taxes = true;
            }
        }
        // Set new taxes cost
        if( $has_taxes )
            $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
    }
}    return $rates;
} break; } }
```